# Suspected Wheel Bearing?

Tags: wheel-bearing

Recently most of the time when driving I can hear a sort of metal on metal/scratch sound every second with a very short half second interval of silence. Almost as if a disc is spinning and then on one region something was to obstruct/touch it, if that makes sense. If my hearing serves me correct it's only coming from the front drivers side region. If I even every so slightly touch the brakes it stops immediately. General acceleration/going into neutral and cruising/being in gear has no immediate impact, sound remains.

I checked my brake pads, evenly worn still have life, my brake disc seems alright as well. Brake caliper bolts are lubricated and fine. Tie rods and other components also seem fine. I also checked for play with the tyre and there is extremely minimal play if any (not 100% it's not from moving other components due to pressure applied on the tyre).

What other components could it be/should I verify?

Comment: Of the several failed bearings I have had , none made noise. I felt it in the steering wheel or the chassis.

Answer (score 1):

How did you go about testing any of the components you say are good? Did you jack the tire off the ground and give it a spin? Just because there is pad left on the brakes doesn't mean that they aren't the source of the noise. It has been my experience, you usually feel wheel bearings going bad (through the steering wheel and floor boards) before you'll hear it, and stepping on the brakes won't have much of an effect on the noise. You stating that it goes away when you press the brakes leads me to think one of the pads is dragging on the rotor. If you jack the front end up and spin the tire, the rest of the road noise which is associated with driving won't come into play and might allow you to hear better what's going on.

Comment: Jacked the car up, removed the tyre and brake pads, checked them, checked caliper bolts. Spun the tyre as well. All the components are relatively new (aware that doesn't detract from fact they could still be faulty) as replaced them myself last year - tie rods, complete struts, stabiliser link and ball joint. Checked for play in all of them i.e. manually by pulling/pushing on them etc. I will try somehow to record the sound as even from YouTube videos doesn't sound like the typical wheel bearing if it is that. For the brake pads would swapping one sides front/back pad be a good test case?

Comment: @Dave1UK - You really shouldn't swap the brake pads any which way. Never a test I'd use to check them. Did you spin the rotor with no brake pads on it?

Comment: @Paulster2 Makes sense. No I didn't, I will try that before proceeding with anything else. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulster2 Haven't had the time yet to check the rotor with no brake pads but will do so this week. However also realised the sound is apparent whilst driving in a certain direction i.e. wheels being turned in a certain direction such as a slight left and stops when in a different direction, would that help pointing to any specific component to also check?

Comment: Front wheel drive? A noise that's more pronounced when turning one way can often be a worn CV joint.